# iPhone - Creating a simple UINavigationBar with a Back button using Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uinavigationbar, back-button, uinavigationitem

No complex things here. I've added in my xib a navigationBar, and I'd like to add a "back" button on its left. But nothing works. I've added "many" other buttons, but I can't achieve adding this one...

Do you know how I may do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add text or a small image for the back button.

In the `viewDidLoad` scope, add:

```
/*  add an image  */
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];

/*  add text  */
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[backButton setText:@"Back"];;
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

Comment: @WrightsCS : No way to do this into IB ??? Where should I find the default back.png image ?

Comment: Theres no way in IB. You can search Goolge for a "home" or "back" button, or create your own using your favorite graphics editor.

Comment: @WrightsCS : what about the "Back button" property into IB for the default navigation item created into the navigation bar ?

Comment: UINavigationController displays a back button when a new controller is pushed. The back button property specifies the title of the button when the current controller is the one which will be returned to.

Comment: @Oliver, not quite sure what property you are referring to.

Comment: @WrightsCS : into the first tab of the navigation item attributes

Comment: @ughoavgfhw : no. I'm talking about IB, not the autogenerated bar.

Comment: could you possibly snap a screen of that property, You may have something different then me.

Comment: @WrightsCS : Uhhh... That seems stupid but I don't know how to make a snapshot on a Macintosh... :-( Add a NavBar into a view, select the navbarItem, it's the first tab in the inspector. You have "Title", "Prompt" and "Back button"

Comment: Oh LOL, thats just for the title of the back button that will display on each child view.

Comment: There is no way to display the standard back button without pushing a second view. You can put in a button in the left spot by dragging it there, but it will show up as a rounded rectangle.

Comment: @WrightsCS : ok ok ok... just a second... So I can set the texte of the back button, but not the back button itself ? That's it ?

Comment: Actually ughoavgfhw, you can programmatically add a button in place of a back button that connects to an action.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw : I'm in a pushed view

Comment: Anyway, the code I provided is what you need. it's very basic, but extremely effective.

Comment: Let's be a little bit precise. I have a navigation controller in my app and I force it not to display its bar. I want to build each bar by myself into each view into IB, to be able to control what I'm doing not having to search everywhere where I did create one or the other button.

Comment: You place that code in the first view, and every child view from that root view will display the back button you created in code. It's not any more difficult than that.

Comment: @WrightsCS : effective ? Perhaps, but I guess I must have several buttons depending on my different title lenght on each view where I use it... And redraw them each time I want to change the button title...

Comment: Im not sure what you are specifically looking for. Your question is how to create a back button. What I have provided is how you create the back button in code. There is no way to create a back button in Interface Builder.

Comment: Coding for the iPhone is a real nightmare. The worst coding environment I've ever seen... 2 weeks just to start to build something I built from A to Z in two weeks too on Androïd. A nightmare. Each simple feature is a headache. I'm going to throw that smartphone through the window.

Comment: @WrightsCS : simple. I don't want the navigation controller autoshow the navbar. For that, I use in the viewDidLoad "self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;" I want to put it by myself into each view in IB, control what is on the view and what is not, including the navBar and its items, into IB. And manage the click by coding and do the calls by myself to the controller.

Comment: A new programming language is not easy to master in only a few weeks. Once you get the hang of it, it can be a fun venture. I feel your frustration with Android. I do not like Java, but maybe one day I will conquer it! There are literally 100's of thousands of example projects, just search google or github for what you are looking for and study the code and techniques. I am certain you will figure out what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: "There is no way to create a back button in Interface Builder"... I'm going to make nightmares with that sentence... In IB, you can add a navbar, you can set the back button title, you have a connection for backBarButtonItem, you can add a button on the left, but... you cannot add a button that looks like the backButton.... I'm crashing my head onto the wall... It hurts.

Comment: @WrightsCS : I didn't knew Java neither before starting the app. As I didn't knew Objective-C before starting the same app for the iPhone.

Comment: @WrightsCS : learn Java, and you'll never return to Objective-C. But if you want to continue coding for the iPhone, never learn Java :-)

Comment: @WrightsCS : With cocoa... Everything is an object... but not everything... Everything is a pointer... but not everything... You can set any object into any object, so you can make all the mistakes you want... It may crash... or not... You must put connections everywhere for nothing. One line of code in Java is 3 lines in Objective-C. XCode can warn you if you set MyObject a = @"test", but no if you set MyObject a = [ins returnMeANSString]; No Way to work with instanciated object, only pointers, even if you don't need them... May I talk about the back bar button ? :-)  Just a standard UI item.

Comment: @WrightsCS: I did not say that you couldn't put a button there. I said you cannot put the back button (meaning with the pointed shape) there. You can put a button there in IB by dragging it in, but it won't get the pointed end.